# How can I delete cookies and temporary Internet files when I do web scraping with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, cookies, web-scraping

So I have a list with about 300 URLs from a webpage that I want to scrape once a day.

So far I am blocked in about 5 min after first webpage scraping.

How can I clear cookies and Internet files each time I navigate to the URL?

Is there a way to simulate kind of more like a human behavior?

```
With ie
    Set wks = wb.Sheets("TESTINGS")

    For j = 22 To 45
    wks.Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, 5)).Interior.ColorIndex = 38
    counter = counter + 1

    mylink1 = wks.Cells(j, 2).Value

    .Visible = True
    .Navigate mylink1

    While .Busy Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend


    Set products = .Document.querySelectorAll(".card.js-product-card")
    t = Timer

    Do
        DoEvents
        ie.Document.parentWindow.execScript "window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);", "javascript"
        Set finalPrices = .Document.querySelectorAll(".card.js-product-card span.final-price")
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3)
        If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
    Loop Until finalPrices.Length = products.Length

    Set sellers = .Document.querySelectorAll(".card.js-product-card .shop.cf a[title]")
    Set availability = .Document.querySelectorAll(".card.js-product-card span.availability")
    Set pname = .Document.querySelectorAll(".location-tab")
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TESTINGS")

        For i = 0 To sellers.Length - 1
If availability.Item(i).innerText = "¢ìåóç ðáñáëáâÞ / ÐáñÜäïóç 1 Ýùò 3 çìÝñåò" Then               
            .Cells(j, 4) = sellers.Item(i)
            .Cells(j, 5) = finalPrices.Item(i).innerText
            .Cells(j, 6) = availability.Item(i).innerText
            .Cells(j, 7) = pname.Item(i).innerText                              
            Exit For              
            End If
   wks.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 5)).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        'MsgBox ("Link Number " & j & "They left " & MaxNumber - counter)
        Application.StatusBar = "Current row " & j & " Progress: " & counter & " of " & MaxNumber & " " & Format(j / MaxNumber, "0%")

        Next

    End With

wks.Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, 5)).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
Next
Call TransferDataFromColumnE17(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TESTINGS"))
.Quit
Set ie = Nothing

End With
```

Comment: We would need to see your existing code.  Your method is a bit unorthodox, and we would need to see the objects you are using to determine how to best access the cookies (if they exist in the objects you're using).

Comment: For clearing cookies check out [this link](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1008563-deleting-ie-temporary-internet-files-cookies-history.html) to see the usage.

Comment: @SIM Do I need to declare some variables?

Comment: It seems I found simpler than earlier `Sub ClearCookies():Shell "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 2":End Sub`. Make newline replacing colon `:`.

Comment: @Robert So Mr Robert any fresh ideas?what whould be the orthodox method for that?

Comment: Anything but Excel VBA would be preferable.  Python and Scrapy, C# and HttpClient, etc.

Comment: Thank you SIM for your answer I think it is working

Comment: BTW Get rid of Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3) and increase the constant MAX instead.

Comment: @SIM Would be worth posting your answer if Maria confirms is working.

Comment: @Qhar thank you, can you open a chat to ask you please?

Comment: No not yet ,I havent

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I just noticed that this is an older post, but better late than never I suppose.

If you want to stick with VBA, You can call the sub below:

```
Public Sub Clear_Browser()
    'clears temporary Internet files
    Shell "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.Cpl, ClearMyTracksByProcess 8"
    'deletes all history
    Shell "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255"
    'deletes cookies
    Shell "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.Cpl, ClearMyTracksByProcess 2"
    'deletes form data
    Shell "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 16"
    'deletes password history
    Shell "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 32"
    'deletes history
    Shell "RunDll32.exe InetCpl.Cpl, ClearMyTracksByProcess 1"
End Sub
```

You can call it in your For Loop to clear every 30 iterations of j like this:

```
  If j Mod 30 = 0 Then
         Clear_Browser
  End If
```

However, automating IE is really, really slow, so I would recommend an adaptation of what I did in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53176142/excel-vba-web-scraping-tables-not-responding-msxml2-serverxmlhttp-6-0-method) post where I used the `MSXML2.ServerXMLhttp.6.0` Method. This method is very fast and is essentially an invisible browser that doesn't hold any cache, history, or cookies. It Sends an HTTP request to the server and receives a response of the desired data.

If you need something really fast though and just all around better, forget *VBA* and use *Python* with the *BeautifulSoup* Library as suggested by @ryguy72.

Comment: `MSXML2.ServerXMLhttp.6.0` is the way

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any particular URL in your post.  I would suspect the site detects you as a bot, and it's blocking you.  I don't think clearing the cookies, or cache, or whatever,  will do anything at all.  Try doing it in Python.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
url = "https://www.pythonforbeginners.com"
content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Export to Excel.  Then you will have everything you need.  It will run MUCH faster and it will be MUCH more stable as well.

Comment: what if there is no python interpreter installed and user lacks admin rights ? What if there is a group policy whitelisting only a predefined list of .exes and python isn't among them ?